# EventMachine UNIX socket connections: how do I use them with Thin running as a service?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, thin

How can I use `EventMachine.connect_unix_domain` while running Thin as a service (using the init script (excerpt) and configuration below). The code directly below is the problem (I get an `eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_unix_server` error). The second code example works, but doesn't allow me to daemonize thin (I don't think). Does Thin not already have a running instance of EventMachine?

UPDATE: Oddly enough: stopping the server (with `service thin stop`), seems to get into the config.ru file and run the app (so it works, until the `stop` command times out and kills the process). What happens when thin stops that could be causing this behavior?

## Problematic Code

```
class Server < Sinatra::Base
# Webserver code removed
end

module Handler
  def receive_data data
    $received_data_changed = 1
    $received_data = data
  end
end

$sock = EventMachine.connect_unix_domain("/tmp/mysock.sock", Handler)
```

## Working Code

```
EventMachine.run do
  class Server < Sinatra::Base
  # Webserver code removed
  end

  module Handler
    def receive_data data
      $received_data_changed = 1
      $received_data = data
    end
  end
  $sock = EventMachine.connect_unix_domain("/tmp/mysock.sock", Handler)
  Server.run!(:port => 4567)
end
```

## Init Script excerpt

```
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
    $DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
```

## Thin Config

```
--- 
chdir: /var/www
environment: development
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []

wait: 30
servers: 1
socket: /tmp/thin.server.sock
daemonize: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was removing the `EventMachine.run do ... end` and simply enclosing the socket connection in an `EM.next_tick{ $sock = EventMachine.connect_unix_domain("/tmp/mysock.sock", Handler) }`.

Could swear I tried this once before... but it works now.

EDIT: Idea for `next_tick` came from [here](https://github.com/tmm1/amqp/issues/21).

Answer (score 0):

Thin is built on top of EventMachine. I think that you should use EventMachine for serving your app. Try to debug further way Thin won't daemonize. (What version are you using?). Also you can  run Thin on another port such as 4000 and then pass that as the upstream server to your proxy-forwarding server, if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: See my edit above. `EventMachine.run do` is definitely blocking the call that runs the app. My primary problem is that I want to run Thin on a UNIX socket, not a port, which I can't seem to do with App.run!